Rename Spl-token
On Ubuntu I made a coin, this coin whenever I send it is called unknown token or BERJW how can I change this name to something else? Like is there a code snippet or a site that allows me to change it?

If you are familiar with JS, you could use Metaplex UMI with the token metadata plugin to update your token details
import {
    keypairIdentity,
    publicKey,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import {
    clusterApiUrl,
    Connection,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
    fetchMetadataFromSeeds,
    findMasterEditionPda,
    mplTokenMetadata,
    updateV1,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

export const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

const umi = createUmi(connection);

export const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from([ <UPDATE WITH SECRET KEY>]));

umi.use(keypairIdentity(keypair)).use(mplTokenMetadata());

async function updateTMDAsset() {
    const mint = publicKey(" "); // update with mint address
    const edition = findMasterEditionPda(umi, { mint });

    const initialMetadata = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint });

    await updateV1(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: umi.identity,
        data: { ...initialMetadata, name: "Updated Asset" },
        primarySaleHappened: true,
        edition,
        isMutable: true,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
}

ref: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update
